# Multiple Where clauses in Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have a simple lambda expression that goes something like this:

```
x=> x.Lists.Include(l => l.Title).Where(l=>l.Title != String.Empty)
```

Now, if I want to add one more where clause to the expression, say, `l.InternalName != String.Empty` then what would the expression be?

Comment: This is a little off-topic but the string class has a method String.IsNullOrEmpty that you can use rather than comparing it against String.Empty

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Can be

```
x => x.Lists.Include(l => l.Title)
     .Where(l => l.Title != String.Empty && l.InternalName != String.Empty)
```

or

```
x => x.Lists.Include(l => l.Title)
     .Where(l => l.Title != String.Empty)
     .Where(l => l.InternalName != String.Empty)
```

When you are looking at `Where` implementation, you can see it accepts a `Func(T, bool)`; that means:

- `T` is your IEnumerable type
- `bool` means it needs to return a boolean value

So, when you do

```
.Where(l => l.InternalName != String.Empty)
//     ^                   ^---------- boolean part
//     |------------------------------ "T" part
```

Comment: Thx. Operators are not mentioned in the documentation page for Queryable.Where.

Answer (score 14):

The lambda you pass to `Where` can include any normal C# code, for example the `&&` operator:

```
.Where(l => l.Title != string.Empty && l.InternalName != string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can include it in the same where statement with the && operator...

```
x=> x.Lists.Include(l => l.Title).Where(l=>l.Title != String.Empty 
    && l.InternalName != String.Empty)
```

You can use any of the comparison operators (think of it like doing an if statement) such as...

```
List<Int32> nums = new List<int>();

nums.Add(3);
nums.Add(10);
nums.Add(5);

var results = nums.Where(x => x == 3 || x == 10);
```

...would bring back 3 and 10.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe

```
x=> x.Lists.Include(l => l.Title)
    .Where(l => l.Title != string.Empty)
    .Where(l => l.InternalName != string.Empty)
```

?

You can probably also put it in the same where clause:

```
x=> x.Lists.Include(l => l.Title)
    .Where(l => l.Title != string.Empty && l.InternalName != string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x=> x.Lists.Include(l => l.Title).Where(l=>l.Title != String.Empty).Where(l => l.Internal NAme != String.Empty)
```

or

```
x=> x.Lists.Include(l => l.Title).Where(l=>l.Title != String.Empty && l.Internal NAme != String.Empty)
```