# .Any causes The cast to value type 'Boolean' failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Complete error message:

> The cast to value type 'Boolean' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Code:

```
 var messages = ctx.tblMessageQueue.Where(o => o.Status == status && o.Region == region);     
 //o.Status is a byte type and not nullable, o.Region is an int type and not nullable.

 if(messages != null && messages.Any()) => Triggers the Error
 {...
 }
```

StackTrace is :

> at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader
>   reader, Int32 ordinal)     at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )     at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper
>   shaper)     at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)     at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   sequence)     at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot)     at 
>           at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)

Comment: Make sure to tag the question with the LINQ provider.

Comment: @user3196525 be responsive if you ask any question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the column values in your `tblMessageQueue` table is `NULL` whereas its corresponding property in the entity class is of type `bool`. If that's the case, here are two suggestions I can think of:

1. Correct the data and table so that it doesn't contain or allow `NULL`
2. Update the entity class property to be nullable: `bool?`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something along the lines of this:

```
var messages = ctx.tblMessageQueue.Where(o => o.Status == status && o.Region == region)
                                  .Where(o => o.Status != null);
```

I'm not certain of the syntax, but you just need to make sure null status messages don't make it into the new variable.

here's an example / similar question - [Multiple Where clauses in Lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748047/multiple-where-clauses-in-lambda-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see any others of your properties in your Message table have null value, if your Message table contain nullable integer then you should consider change your Message Entity class to "int?" type.