# Entity Framework, how to use IQueryable with multiple where are translated to SQL?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

Consider everything here is `IQueryable`

1. Do these 2 examples generate the same SQL query?
2. Adding multiple `Where` is translated to SQL as AND ?
3. Is there any way to add multiple `Where` connected as OR?

Example 1:

```
client = client.Where(c => c.FirstName.StartsWith("F")); 
client = client.Where(c => c.LastName.StartsWith("T")); 
return client.ToList();
```

Example 2:

```
client = client.Where(c => c.FirstName.StartsWith("F") AND c.LastName.StartsWith("T")); 
return client.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple where clauses are valid. It's equivalent to:

```
client = client.Where(c=> c.FirstName.StartsWith("F") && c.LastName.StartsWith("T"));
```

It will get sent to SQL in your case on the .ToList() call.
Other cases where it will get executed include:
.Any(), .First()/.Last()/.FirstOrDefault()/etc., .Count().

Answer (score 1):

Try Code

```
client = client.Where(c => (c.FirstName.StartsWith("F") && c.LastName.StartWith("T"))).ToList();
```

Or Condition Used

```
 client = client.Where(c => (c.FirstName.StartsWith("F") || c.LastName.StartWith("T"))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to add multiple condition in LINQ. Please Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748047/multiple-where-clauses-in-lambda-expressions)! to get more about this. Thank You.